# My MYSQL code won't run through a syntax checker

Tags: mysql, sql

Online SQL syntax checkers have been giving me a lot of guff about my simple SQL code, and I don't understand why...

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DB ;
USE DB ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers( 
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
   LAST_NAME TEXT,
   FIRST_NAME TEXT,
   COMPUTER_ID TEXT);
```

I pretty much copied this code from some SQL examples.  I'm using mySQL and testing on SQLfiddle.com which is set to use MYSQL 5.6.  It says Access denied for user 'user_9_79940c'@'%' to database 'db' if I have the first two lines there and if I remove them it says about the create table that I have a syntax error near AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: there is not string data type, try with VARCHAR(LENGTH) OR TEXT

Comment: *giving me a lot of guff* is an absolutely useless problem description. What **specific problem** are you having with the SQL you've dumped here with no problem description? And while you're making the [edit] to provide that information, you can improve the title of your post to something descriptive of the issue you're having or question you're asking. Everyone's SQL is broken; if it wasn't they wouldn't be posting it here looking for help. Your title should be something that will be useful to a future user here seeing it in a list of search results.

Comment: which database are you using sql server or mysql? CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS won't work with sql server. Please provide details what you want and what have you done till now

Comment: "an error"? Do you go to a doctor and say "Doctor, it hurts somewhere, after I do something"? Please, error messages are there for a reason. What kind of an error? Where? After the edit: syntax error, where? I happen to have done the diagnostics myself, but... you can't be certain the next problem will be as easy for us to remote-diagnose.

Comment: Making it AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY fixed the create table body, but I don't understand why.  The create db and use db lines still get an access denied error.  Could that just be the website?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not allowed to create or switch databases on SQLFiddle. On your own MySQL instance, you might be able to, depending on what permissions you have. This is why the first two lines do not work in the SQLFiddle; the database is pre-created and pre-selected for you, and you are sandboxed in it.

The `CREATE TABLE` command will throw a syntax error complaining about `AUTO INCREMENT` - that is not a keyword, it should be written `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

There is still an error there: "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key". There is only one auto column, but it is not a key yet. So, we'll make it one, by appending `PRIMARY KEY`. This works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers( 
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   LAST_NAME TEXT,
   FIRST_NAME TEXT,
   COMPUTER_ID TEXT);
```

Note that `PRIMARY KEY` will imply `NOT NULL`, so `NOT NULL` is unnecessary, and can be deleted without consequence.